# Add filtering on top of Stored Procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

Currently I am dynamically building a SQL `SELECT` statement that has filters at the end based on a users selections in three different ListBoxes.

So I end up having...

```
SELECT 
    whatever 
FROM 
    dbo.Table
WHERE 
    (columnA = listB1.Item[x] OR columnA = listB1.Item[y])
    AND
    (columnB = listB2.Item[g] OR columnA = listB2.Item[h])
    ....
```

What I want to do is store the `SELECT ... FROM ...` as a stored procedure, and then use the remaining `WHERE...` portion as a parameter I guess.

I tried experimenting in SQL Server Management Studio to see if I could just create a stored procedure with a parameter at the end...

```
SELECT whatever 
FROM dbo.Table @PARAM
```

... where PARAM = 'WHERE ... and ... or ' and it didn't like that.

Is it possible to grab a stored procedure, open up the actual content of it, and concatenate my `WHERE...` onto the end of it?

Thanks. I'm no DB expert, so any other ways of doing this would greatly be appreciated.

EDIT: I should add that the AND / OR combination statements are variable.

So one time it could be

```
SELECT whatever 
FROM dbo.TABLE

<no filter>
```

or

```
SELECT whatever 
FROM dbo.TABLE
WHERE (colA = this)
  AND (colB = that)
```

or

```
SELECT whatever 
FROM dbo.TABLE
WHERE (colA = this OR colA = that OR colA = who)
  AND (colC = him)
```

Comment: Microsoft SQL Server

Comment: Then you should get in the habit of adding a `sql-server` tag to your question, to make that clear

Answer (score 1):

You can do this by using dynamic queries in stored procedure. Create SP with static **select** query and pass the **where** clause as **parameter**.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE SP_GetFromDB
(
    @Param VARCHAR(200)
)
AS 
BEGIN

    DECLARE @Query VARCHAR(2000) = ''
    SELECT @Query =  'SELECT Column1, Column2, * FROM dbo.MyTable
    WHERE ' + @Param
    EXECUTE (@Query)
END
```

In application side, form a string for where clause something like

```
string query = "(columnA = " + listB1.Item[x] + " OR columnA = " + listB1.Item[y] ") AND (columnB = " + listB2.Item[g] + " OR columnA = " + listB2.Item[h] ")" ;
```

and pass this as **@param** for the Stored Procedure.

Comment: Thanks, storing the static part as an SP and build the dynamic portion as a string was the goal. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Create the proc and pass in the users selections as parameters.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE YourNewSP (x,y,g,h)
as 
begin

    SELECT whatever FROM dbo.Table
    WHERE (columnA = x OR columnA = y)
    AND
    (columnB = g OR columnA = h)

end
```

Comment: The problem is that I can have a variable amount of OR statements and AND statements.

Comment: Based on what? You can use a trick of (columnA = @ValueA OR '@ValueA is null) to handle the cases when a user didn't select a value, or you don't want to restrict on that column.

Answer (score 0):

Since SQL Server 2008 you can pass table valued parameters to stored procedures.
So, for each of your list boxes, you could add one table valued parameter.
Then use a WHERE like

```
WHERE columnA IN(SELECT theValue FROM @listBoxAValues) 
   AND columnB IN(SELECT theValue FROM @listBoxBValues) 
   AND columnC IN(SELECT theValue FROM @listBoxCValues)
```

To get around the case that there are no values provided for any of the three parameters you can pre-check it like

```
DECLARE @CountA BIT = (SELECT count(*) FROM @listBoxAValues)
DECLARE @CountB BIT = (SELECT count(*) FROM @listBoxBValues)
DECLARE @CountC BIT = (SELECT count(*) FROM @listBoxCValues)
```

and then rewrite the WHERE like

```
WHERE (@CountA = 0 OR columnA IN(SELECT theValue FROM @listBoxAValues)) 
  AND (@CountB = 0 OR columnB IN(SELECT theValue FROM @listBoxBValues)) 
  AND (@CountC = 0 OR columnC IN(SELECT theValue FROM @listBoxCValues))
```

To be able to pass a table valued parameter you have to create a new table valued type in your database first:

```
CREATE TYPE MyType AS TABLE(theValue int);
```

Given all your three list boxes could use the same type, your stored procedure would start like

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.pr_myProc (
    @listBoxAValues MyType, 
    @listBoxBValues MyType, 
    @listBoxCValues MyType)
```